# How do I Marshal a c/cpp struct containing a function pointer?

Tags: c#, audio, sdl-2

Good Morning, I am attempting to create a C# dot net core wrapper for the Audio functionality of SDL.
In particular,
I am attempting to create a wrapper for https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LoadWAV

The existing code is:

To represent the non basic types being marshalled:

```
    public delegate void SDL_AudioCallback(IntPtr userdata, byte[] stream,out int len);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SDL_AudioSpec
    {
        public int freq;
        public ushort format;
        public byte channels;
        public byte silence;
        public ushort samples;
        public UInt32 size;
        public IntPtr callback;
        IntPtr userdata;
    }
    public class SDL_AudioSpecPtr
    {
        public readonly IntPtr NativePointer;

        public SDL_AudioSpecPtr(IntPtr pointer)
        {
            NativePointer = pointer;
        }

        public static implicit operator IntPtr(SDL_AudioSpecPtr Sdl2Window) => Sdl2Window.NativePointer;
        public static implicit operator SDL_AudioSpecPtr(IntPtr pointer) => new SDL_AudioSpecPtr(pointer);
    }
```

Importing the Method signature:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate SDL_AudioSpec SDL_LoadWAV_t(string file, IntPtr spec, byte[] audio_buf, out UInt32 audio_len);
private static SDL_LoadWAV_t s_sdl_LoadWAV = LoadFunction<SDL_LoadWAV_t>("SDL_LoadWAV");
public static void SDL_LoadWAV(string file, IntPtr spec, byte[] audio_buf, out UInt32 audio_len) => s_sdl_LoadWAV(file,spec,audio_buf,out audio_len);
```

Attempting to call the function yields null exception:

```
Sdl2Native.SDL_Init(SDLInitFlags.Audio);
SDL_AudioSpec spec = new SDL_AudioSpec();
byte[] bytes=new byte[20000];
uint len;
SDL_AudioSpec* specptr = &spec;
Sdl2Native.SDL_LoadWAV(@"G:\Assets\sfx_movement_jump2.wav", (IntPtr)specptr, bytes, out len);
```

Comment: Where is your actual callback function, you are not passing anything for that?

Comment: I am not passing anything for that... I am trying to convert this example of playing a sound to c#.
https://gist.github.com/armornick/3447121

Answer (score 0):

**You should rely more heavily on the CLR's marshalling rather than doing your own, it's a lot easier to make serious errors.**

Furthermore:

- Strings need marshalling to ANSI with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`
- You shouldn't just convert `&` pointer to `*` like that, the struct needs marshalling.
- A callback given to unmanaged code needs to be held onto, so that the GC doesn't sweep it away.

> It's unclear why you have a `LoadFunction` setup rather than just using standard P/Invoke, but I've run with that.

So the delegate should be

```cs
private static SDL_AudioSpec SDL_LoadWAV_t(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string file,
    in SDL_AudioSpec spec,
    ref byte[] audio_buf,
    out UInt32 audio_len);
```

and then `SDL_AudioSpec` struct should declare the callback

```cs
public SDL_AudioCallback callback;
```

The callback is wrong also: `len` is not a `out` parameter, it is by-value; and it's unclear if `stream` should be `ref` or `out` or `in`, I think `out`.

```cs
public delegate void SDL_AudioCallback(IntPtr userdata, out byte[] stream, int len);
```

Depending on how long the callback is being used for, you need to hold onto it

- If it is just used within a single call, and is not held by unmanaged code, then place `GC.KeepAlive(callback);` after the call
- If unmanaged code holds it further then you would need to store it in a field somewhere, where you can guarantee it will not be deleted by GC before the last callback

Your calling code is then:

```cs
var callbackDlgt = new SDL_AudioCallback(myCallbackFunction);
SDL_AudioSpec spec = new SDL_AudioSpec{
    callback = callbackDlgt,
// set other values here
};
byte[] bytes = new byte[20000];
Sdl2Native.SDL_LoadWAV(@"G:\Assets\sfx_movement_jump2.wav", in specptr, ref bytes, out uint len);
GC.KeepAlive(callbackDlgt);
```